# NodeJS - Handle TLS renegotiation client side

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs server with some API endpoints. One of them requires client authentication through SSL certificates. That works fine if I go to this endpoint with Firefox or Chrome but not with a custom nodejs client.

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 1337,
  path: '/api/nodes_endpoint/json/20?data=eeeeeee',
  method: 'GET',
  key: fs.readFileSync('/home/jose/Escritorio/test.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/jose/Escritorio/test.cert'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

After the server request the TLS renegotiation, the object that should contain the client certificate is NULL, so I suppose that the client is not handling correctly the TLS renegotiation.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of search I landed to the solution in a [Github Issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2259).

Solved by adding

> secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION

to options when creating the https server:

```
https.createServer({ secureOptions: ... })
```